# Next.js Fast Refresh server keeps crashing

Tags: next.js

I am new to Next.js and my initial experience with its fast refresh functionality has been outright horrendous. I have an external stylesheet being imported by my component. Not always, but randomly, when I make a change the server crashes. I have ensured it is none of the potential causes listed in the [Next docs](https://stackoverflow.com) for avoiding this issue but it continues to persist. I have heard so many great things about Next.js so I didn't expect the development experience for something so basic to be so frustrating.

All I am doing is trying to implement a basic flexbox layout in this React component using an external stylesheet. As you will see all the background images I am using are inside the public folder as the Next docs say to do with static assets
[image: My folder structure as I know Next cares about that too]

```
import "./GalleryPage.css";

export default function GalleryPage() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Gallery</h1>
      <div className="flex-container">
        <div className="flex-item red-porsche"></div>
        <div className="flex-item bimmers"></div>
        <div className="flex-item marlboro"></div>
        <div className="flex-item porsches"></div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

GalleryPage.css

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-item {
  height: 250px;
  width: 150px;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: rgb(71, 45, 95);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.red-porsche {
  background-image: url("../../public/red-porsche.jpeg");
}

.bimmers {
  background-image: url("../../public/bimmers.jpeg");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- As per the above code looks like you have stored images in `public` folder
- If thats correct then, your **path** given to images stored in public folder **isn't correct**, you don't need to include public folder name in path just start path from source `/` in public folder.

Read here about public folder : https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/installation#the-public-folder-optional

**In your `GalleryPage.css` change path**

```
.red-porsche {
    background-image: url("/red-porsche.jpeg");
}

.bimmers {
    background-image: url("/bimmers.jpeg");
}
```

- If you want to store images in a sub folder inside public then, **for example** : *I want to store images in a images folder in public folder*
- So I will create a images folder inside public Keep image files in it
- when using them I will give path/src as `/images/imageFilename.extension`
- **I will also recommend you to read about CSS Modules.** Read here CSS Modules : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/styling/css-modules
- **Regarding the crashes** if you have kept auto-save on after some delay, then disable it. It causes file to be saved, which may have incomplete code.